# SQL server 2014 erro na instalação

Tags: sql-server

Boa noite pessoal! estou tentando instalar o sql server 2014 express, mas no momento da instalaçao acontece os seguintes erros, o que pode ser? Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**LOG**
O log de erro é esse. me desculpem se tiver outra forma de mandar esse erro, não sei como faz.

> ```
> Overall summary:
>   Final result:                  Falha: consulte os detalhes abaixo
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893607
>   Start time:                    2016-11-05 11:23:00
>   End time:                      2016-11-05 11:32:14
>   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features.
> Troubleshooting information for those features:
>   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use as seguintes informações para corrigir o erro, desinstale o recurso e execute o processo de instalação novamente.
>   Next step for Replication:     Use as seguintes informações para corrigir o erro, desinstale o recurso e execute o processo de instalação novamente.
>
>
> Machine Properties:
>   Machine name:                  STUDIONE-PC
>   Machine processor count:       4
>   OS version:                    Windows 8
>   OS service pack:               
>   OS region:                     Brasil
>   OS language:                   Português (Brasil)
>   OS architecture:               x64
>   Process architecture:          64 Bits
>   OS clustered:                  Não
>
> Product features discovered:
>   Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
>   SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Serviços de Mecanismo de Banco de Dados  1033                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Serviços de Mecanismo de Banco de Dados  1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Replicação do SQL Server                 1033                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Replicação do SQL Server                 1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          Ferramentas de Geranciamento - Básicas   1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          Ferramentas de Gerenciamento - Completas 1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          Conectividade das Ferramentas de Cliente 1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          Compatibilidade das Ferramentas de Cliente com Versões Anteriores 1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          SDK de Ferramentas de Cliente            1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>   SQL Server 2014                                                          LocalDB                                  1046                 Express Edition      12.1.4100.1     Não        Sim       
>
> Package properties:
>   Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
>   ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
>   Type:                          RTM
>   Version:                       12
>   Installation location:         C:\Users\StudiOne\Downloads\pt_sql_server_2014_express_with_tools_with_service_pack_1_x64_6674722\x64\setup\
>   Installation edition:          Express
>
>   Slipstream:                    True
>   SP Level                       1
>
> Product Update Status:
>   Êxito: KB 3058865
>
> Product Updates Selected for Installation:
>   Title:                         Microsoft SQL Server 2014  Express with Tools SP1
>   Knowledge Based Article:       KB 3058865
>   Version:                       12.1.4100.0
>   Architecture:                  x64
>   Language:                      1046
>
>   Update Source:                 Slipstream
>
>
> Configurações de Entrada do Usuário:
>   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
>   AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 AUTORIDADE NT\SERVIÇO DE REDE
>   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
>   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
>   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
>   ASDATADIR:                     Data
>   ASLOGDIR:                      Log
>   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
>   ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
>   ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <vazio>
>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <vazio>
>   ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <vazio>
>   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
>   CLTCTLRNAME:                   <vazio>
>   CLTRESULTDIR:                  <vazio>
>   CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
>   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <vazio>
>   CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <vazio>
>   CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <vazio>
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
>   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0
>   CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
>   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
>   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <vazio>
>   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <vazio>
>   CTLRUSERS:                     <vazio>
>   ENABLERANU:                    true
>   ENU:                           false
>   ERRORREPORTING:                false
>   FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION
>   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
>   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <vazio>
>   FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <vazio>
>   FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <vazio>
>   HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
>   INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
>   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
>   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <vazio>
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>   INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
>   INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
>   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
>   ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <vazio>
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
>   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <vazio>
>   MATRIXNAME:                    <vazio>
>   NPENABLED:                     0
>   PID:                           *****
>   QUIET:                         false
>   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
>   ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
>   RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
>   RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
>   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <vazio>
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <vazio>
>   RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   SAPWD:                         <vazio>
>   SECURITYMODE:                  <vazio>
>   SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <vazio>
>   SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <vazio>
>   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
>   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           StudiOne-PC\StudiOne
>   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <vazio>
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <vazio>
>   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <vazio>
>   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <vazio>
>   SQMREPORTING:                  false
>   TCPENABLED:                    0
>   UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
>   UpdateEnabled:                 true
>   UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
>   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
>   X86:                           false
>
>   Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161105_112300\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:
>   Feature:                       Serviços de Mecanismo de Banco de Dados
>   Status:                        Falha: consulte os logs para obter detalhes
>  Reason for failure:            Erro durante o processo de instalação do recurso.
>   Next Step:                     Use as seguintes informações para corrigir o erro, desinstale o recurso e execute o processo de instalação novamente.
>   Component name:                Recursos de Instância dos Serviços do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados do SQL Server
>   Component error code:          0x851A0019
>   Error description:             Não foi possível encontrar o identificador de inicialização do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados.
>   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025
>
>   Feature:                       Replicação do SQL Server
>   Status:                        Falha: consulte os logs para obter detalhes
>   Reason for failure:            Um erro em uma dependência do recurso está ocasionando falha no processo de instalação do recurso.
>   Next Step:                     Use as seguintes informações para corrigir o erro, desinstale o recurso e execute o processo de instalação novamente.
>   Component name:                Recursos de Instância dos Serviços do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados do SQL Server
>   Component error code:          0x851A0019
>   Error description:             Não foi possível encontrar o identificador de inicialização do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados.
>   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161105_112300\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
> ```

Comment: Posta o arquivo de log  que está especificado no caminho destacado na parte inferior da tela.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamos, habilitou o .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, antes de iniciar a instalação do SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, o que está a instalar é o SQL Server 2014 Express com SP1, pacote SQLEXPRWT_X64. Há uma compilação mais recente, já com o service pack 2: [SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=53167).  Mas esta não é a causa do erro de instalação.

Antes de instalar o SQL Server, é sugerida a leitura atenta do documento [Requisitos de hardware e software para a instalação do SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx), que contém o que é necessário para uma instalação bem sucedida.

Pelo log obtém-se a informação de que o computador está com o Windows 8, 64 bits, idioma português. Nesse caso, antes de iniciar a instalação do SQL Server é necessário habilitar o .NET Framework 3.5, conforme consta nos requisitos de componentes: *“Se você executar a Instalação em um computador com o (...) Windows 8, deverá habilitar o .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 antes de instalar o SQL Server 2014”.*

Ainda com relação ao .NET Framework, há a seguinte observação:
 *“Se você estiver instalando as edições SQL Server Express, verifique se uma conexão da Internet está disponível no computador. A Instalação do SQL Server baixa e instala o .NET Framework 4 porque ele não está incluído na mídia do SQL Server Express”.*

Se não necessita de replicação, então sugiro que não marque essa opção na instalação. A edição Express somente atua como assinante (*subscriber*), em replicações. Detalhes em [Recursos compatíveis com as edições do SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Replication).